# ANTLR4 error when using identifier but not when using literal

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Testing the following simple grammar.

```
grammar SQL;
selectStatement: SELECT selectElements EOF;
selectElements: (star='*' | ID ) (',' ID)*;
ID: ID_LITERAL;
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
fragment ID_LITERAL: [A-Z_$0-9]*? [A-Z_$]+? [A-Z_$0-9]*;
SELECT: 'SELECT';
```

Given the input `SELECT *` it produces the following errors:

```
line 1:0 missing 'SELECT' at 'SELECT'
line 1:7 extraneous input '*' expecting <EOF>
```

While changing `SELECT` identifier to inline literal in the `selectStatement` results in the following grammar, that parses the same input without errors. Why?

```
grammar SQL;
selectStatement: 'SELECT' selectElements EOF;
selectElements: (star='*' | ID ) (',' ID)*;
ID: ID_LITERAL;
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
fragment ID_LITERAL: [A-Z_$0-9]*? [A-Z_$]+? [A-Z_$0-9]*;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The patterns `[A-Z_$0-9]*? [A-Z_$]+? [A-Z_$0-9]*` and `'SELECT'` both match on the input `SELECT *` and they both produce a match of the same length (i.e. they both match `SELECT` and then leave `*` as the rest of the input). In cases like this, ANTLR (like most lexer generators) applies the rule that comes first in the grammar. In your first grammar that's `ID`. So `SELECT *` is lexed as `ID, WS, '*'`, not `SELECT, WS, '*'`.

If you move the rule `SELECT: 'SELECT';` before the definition of `ID`, it will work as you want it to.